# Can buffers in RSA_private_decrypt/RSA_public_encrypt overlap?

Tags: openssl, rsa

Can buffers in openssl's RSA_private_decrypt/RSA_public_encrypt overlap?
By buffers i mean second and third args - `unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not documented. However, OpenSSL itself uses `RSA_private_decrypt()` with the same pointer for `from` and `to`, in `ssl/s3_srvr.c` (seen in OpenSSL 0.9.8o source code), so it must be safe.